# How to calculate the totals of records after filter is applied but before pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails 5 app.
In this app I am sending JSON data to a Backbone/Marionette app.

I want to get the total number of records matching a specific set of criterias but I only get the TOTAL number of records and not the count of records matching. I am also using pagination so I need to get the totals before the pagination takes affect.

This is my controller code:

```
@total = @survey.pulses.count
@pulses = @survey.pulses.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
@pulses = @pulses.this_month if params[:period] == "this_month"
@pulses = @pulses.this_week if params[:period] == "this_week"
@pulses = @pulses.today if params[:period] == "today"
```

Comment: Could you provide your `render json:` code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way:

```
@pulses = @survey.pulses
@pulses = @pulses.this_month if params[:period] == "this_month"
@pulses = @pulses.this_week if params[:period] == "this_week"
@pulses = @pulses.today if params[:period] == "today"

@total  = @pulses.size
@pulses = @survey.pulses.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
```

I'd recommend you to use pagination gem to save your time and don't reinvent the wheel :). eg: [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari), [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), ... They contain a lot of helpers such as `total_count` (before pagination), configurations, pagination links generator (including CSS theme), ...